# Is there any way to call angular 7 application from angular js application(Single Page Applications)

Tags: angularjs, angular

**Use Case**: The Angular Js application will have different components (say, the header of the application contains two components(View 1, View2). The idea is to build a different application for each of the component(view1,view2) using angular 7 but to view the contents of the application in the application built-in angular js (meaning the header, footer of the base application built-in angular js should remain same and when the user clicks on lets say, view1, it should be able to display contents of view1 application built in Angular 7 giving the concept of SPA.

> Application1:built on angular JS
>
> ```
> VIEW1      VIEW2
> ```
>
> VIEW1-->application built on angular 7

When the user clicks on View 1 then in the application 1 it should be able to display

> VIEW1   VIEW 2
>
> //Contents of View 1//

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your `View1`, `View2` as custom elements (https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [View1Component],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  entryComponents: [View1Component]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const customButton = createCustomElement(View1Component, { injector });
    customElements.define('app-view1', View1Component);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

and thus reuse them in any other application you want (including your AngularJS one)

```
<!--AngularJS template-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <app-news-signup></app-news-signup>

    <!-- Angular files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- Using component -->
    <app-view1></app-view1>
</body>
</html>
```